# Array filter using keep_if

Tags: ruby

I have an array like this:

```
array = ["john-56", "admin-57", "duke-58", "duke-65", 
         "john-56", "admin-57", "roger-65", "roger-15"]
```

I want to keep only the elements that are duplicated, in this case I expect to get this result:

```
["admin-57","admin-57","john-56","john-56"]
```

I've tried using the `keep_if` method like this:

```
array.keep_if { |x,y| x==y }
```

But it leaves `array` empty.

Comment: At each iteration `keep_if` pass only one argument to the block. What would you expect `x` and `y` to be? Are you trying to keep only the druplicated elements?

Comment: @toro2k: I am doing it wrong then. I would want it to compare each element to each other and keep the duplicates like my expected result above

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Maybe not the more efficient, but one line:

```
array.select { |x| array.count(x) == 2 }.uniq
```

@edit(thanks to Jounty)

If you have values than can appear more than two times

```
array.select { |x| array.count(x) > 1 }.uniq
```

Comment: what is arr in the above code? I think you meant array. It works fine. Thanks

Comment: Thanks, just a typo I made. I used to test array with arr variable

Comment: This works, but just bear in mind that it won't behave as expected if there are more than two of a single element in the original array. Maybe `> 1` would be a better check.

Comment: Absolutely joonty, I just think that the word duplicate in the question stands for values that can be present maximum two times

Comment: +1 for that I agree with you, There might be more then 2 but I took an example of only 2 duplicates

Answer (score 3):

`Array#keep_if` only passes the current element in the iteration.

You could use:

`duplicates = array.keep_if { |x| array.count(x) > 1 }.uniq`

Or:

`duplicates = array.uniq | array`

Answer (score 1):

For efficiency's sake, count them all first and then filter them based on the calculated count

```
array = %w[ john-56 admin-57 duke-58  duke-65
            john-56 admin-57 roger-65 roger-15 ]

begin
  counts = {}
  array.each { |name| counts[name] = counts[name].to_i + 1 }
  array.keep_if { |name| counts[name] > 1 }
end

p array
```

**output**

```
["john-56", "admin-57", "john-56", "admin-57"]
```

Alternatively, if you don't want the filtered elements to appear multiple times, write

```
begin
  counts = {}
  array.each { |name| counts[name] = counts[name].to_i + 1 }
  array = counts.select { |k, v| v > 1 }.keys
end

p array
```

**output**

```
["john-56", "admin-57"]
```

Answer (score 1):

```
array = %w[ 
  john-56   admin-57 
  duke-58   duke-65
  john-56   admin-57 
  roger-65  roger-15 
]

counts = Hash.new(0)
array.each {|name| counts[name] += 1}

results = []
counts.each do |key, count|
  results += [key]*count if count > 1
end

p results

--output:--
["john-56", "john-56", "admin-57", "admin-57"]
```